# What are the performance benefits and drawbacks of toe socks over normal socks?

Tags: performance, socks

I bought a pair of Injinji toe socks recently to try them out. To date, I haven't noticed a huge difference in the way I perform my physical activities (mostly kung fu and an occasional run). If there is a difference, I'm not physically perceiving it at all. I have noticed that the material does [make a difference in reducing moisture](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/473/do-athletic-socks-make-a-difference-to-performance), but the sock's primary design and function eludes me.

What is the purpose of the toe sock's design, and what effect does separating the toes in a sock have on the bio-mechanical performance of the foot when doing various sports-related activities?

Comment: Try putting on toe socks in Vibrams and you'll know the difference :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some runners, especially some ultra-runners, get blisters in between the toes. Injinjis stop that process by being toe-socks.

You can do the same thing by taping each toe individually with special athletic tape or duct tape.